# Views alpha and frame property spoil when UITextFields first responder changes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield

I have a view (Lets called `thirdStackView`) and two `textfield` (Lets called them textfield `b` and `c`).

In my `viewdidload`, I give their anchors and make textfields alpha to 0, also y frame of textfields to -100. With a button tap, I move `thirdstachview` out of screen with an animation and make textfields visible and make their frame +100.

My problem is that when I change textfield, `thirdstackview` started to seen on screen and textfields positions move back to ones I gave in `viewdidload`. Also when I dismiss keyboard, this problem occurs.

I guess It is something about `layoutIfneeded()` but What can be the problem?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    thirdStackView.anchor(self.btnStackView.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.emergenyBtn.topAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 13, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    self.createTextField(placeHolderText: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_TF_TCKNID), titleText: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_TF_TCKNID), imageName: "id-icon",leftButtons: [.backDisabled,.forward], rightButtons: [.cancel],textField: idTextField)
    idTextField.tag = 1
    idTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    idTextField.anchor(self.btnStackView.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 30, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 30, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 40)
    idTextField.alpha = 0
    self.createTextField(placeHolderText: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_TF_PHONE), titleText: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_TF_PHONE), imageName: "phone-icon",leftButtons: [.back,.forward], rightButtons: [.cancel],textField: phoneTextField)
    phoneTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    phoneTextField.tag = 2
    phoneTextField.anchor(idTextField.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 30, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 30, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 40)
    phoneTextField.alpha = 0
}
```

My animation function;

```
@objc func adminBtnTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    if(btnTapped){
        UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.emergenyBtn.frame.origin.y -= 20
        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.thirdStackView.frame.origin.y += self.view.bounds.height

            self.bgView.frame.origin.y += self.view.bounds.height
            self.backBtn.frame.origin.x += self.view.bounds.width

            self.idTextField.frame.origin.y += 100
            self.idTextField.alpha = 1.0
            self.phoneTextField.frame.origin.y += 100
            self.phoneTextField.alpha = 1.0
            self.passTextField.frame.origin.y += 100
            self.passTextField.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (_) in
            //self.emergenyBtn.setTitle("Giriş Yap", for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        btnTapped = false
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `clipToBounds = true` to the view.

Comment: I gave it to both thirdStackView and superview but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

When I make superviews "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" attribute to false, It solved. I think, when It is true, auto layout constraints messed up.

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

For gurus that this answer is not enough, you can check official Apple document

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco

From Apple Document

> Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional constraints to modify this size or position without introducing conflicts.